# How to remove malformatted escaped backslashes from json?

Tags: json, python-3.x, decode

Given a json file which contains lots of arrays/objects, and the variable `_json` equals the following:

```
{
   "response":{
      "data":[
         {
            "a":"Foo",
            "b":"Bar",
            "name":"\\\\""John Doe\\\\""",
            "gender":"male"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

When I run `json.loads(_json)['response']['data']`, python raises the exception:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter
```

Placing `r` before the json string doesn't work, as it appears to be that `json.loads` still chokes on escapes since the error happens around here `"John Doe\\\\"""`. There may also be cases with more backslashes.

Is there a way to remove these backslashes? Maybe with regex?

I would highly appreciate any feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MisterMiyagi but sadly I cannot change _whatever is producing_ the json data as I download the json file from an online source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is not valid json.  Fix it upstream.  If you want to patch it up here, then this should do the trick:

```
json.loads(_json.replace('\\\\"',''))['response']['data']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @AllanWind but I still get the same error. Any idea why?

Comment: It should be `'\\\\"'` instead of `'\\\\""'`

Comment: @user13581602 it worked for me the way I wrote it but tweaked it as suggested.